# Postgresql "ERROR: column ... does not exist" In A Simple Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

The query is:

```
select *
from "someTable"  
where "id" = "9gf1gf3123";
```

Postgresql gives me the error `column does not exist` while there wasn't a problem with my sql statement. The id exists, the table exists, I want to see everyting in my table, but does not work.
There are a lot of questions about this error but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, I was writing string with `"`, not with `'`.
When I changed the query like:

```
select *
from "userGroupUserOrganizations"  
where "id" = '9fce8e9b-597a-4100-bb3c-efb86aaa83ae';
```

it worked

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS